# Comparing contents of a arraylist<string,string>with arraylist<hashmap<string,string>> in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap

I am retrieving a arraylistfrom the remote server and arraylist> from the SQLite database. I have to compare both the contents of the contents of the database to see which of them are equal.
How can i do so?

Comment: retrieving the contents from both the databases...i don;t know how to proceed further

Comment: What is an ArrayList<String, String>? An ArrayList only takes one type.